# Gitkit Android : gms.StatusHelper Status from wire: INVALID_AUDIENCE status: null

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

I downloaded the Android starter app an year ago and had written my code on top of it. The Google authentication used to work just fine till some time ago.
I have Google, Facebook and Yahoo authentication enabled.
I have implemented Gitkit v3 on my website where Google login is working fine currently.

Right now, on my Android app, custom user id authentication is working properly but Google authentication is not.

When Gmail Id is selected, nothing happens: neither `onSignIn()` nor `onSignInFailed()` gets fired.

Was any server side code changes implemented in this part in the last one year which was not backward compatible ?

===================================

In logcat, the following exception is seen when a Gmail Id is selected for Sign In :

```
10-16 21:29:40.928 6453-14199/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient: Unrecoverable auth exception: Unknown
10-16 21:29:40.928 6453-14199/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
10-16 21:29:40.928 6453-14199/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
10-16 21:29:40.928 6453-14199/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
10-16 21:29:40.928 6453-14199/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at com.google.identitytoolkit.idp.google.GoogleIdpClient$1.call(GoogleIdpClient.java:131)
10-16 21:29:40.928 6453-14199/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at com.google.identitytoolkit.idp.google.GoogleIdpClient$1.call(GoogleIdpClient.java:125)
10-16 21:29:40.928 6453-14199/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at com.google.identitytoolkit.executor.ProgressRequestExecutor$2.doInBackground(ProgressRequestExecutor.java:84)
10-16 21:29:40.928 6453-14199/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at com.google.identitytoolkit.executor.ProgressRequestExecutor$2.doInBackground(ProgressRequestExecutor.java:71)
10-16 21:29:40.928 6453-14199/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
10-16 21:29:40.928 6453-14199/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-16 21:29:40.928 6453-14199/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
10-16 21:29:40.928 6453-14199/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
10-16 21:29:40.928 6453-14199/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
10-16 21:29:40.928 6453-14199/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-16 21:29:40.933 6453-6480/com.application.my_app E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9f1fb160
```

==========================

**UPDATE 1**
I tried using a new Client ID for Android and using it in my Python endpoint code. This did not help.

==========================

**UPDATE 2**
I created a new `Client ID for Web application` and used it in endpoint python file ( as `WEB_CLIENT_ID` ) and in AndroidManifest.xml ( as value of `identitytoolkit.server_client_id` ).  The following exception still comes :

```
10-18 09:43:38.000 12063-15754/? W/GLSActivity: gms.StatusHelper Status from wire: INVALID_AUDIENCE status: null
10-18 09:43:38.000 12063-15754/? I/GLSUser: [GLSUser] getAuthtoken(<ELLIDED:-2092860235>, audience:server:client_id:My_NEW_Client_Id__For_Web_Application.apps.googleusercontent.com) -> status: UNKNOWN)
10-18 09:43:38.000 12063-15754/? I/GLSUser: [GLSUser] Extracting token using key: Auth
10-18 09:43:38.000 12063-15754/? W/GLSActivity: gms.StatusHelper Status from wire: INVALID_AUDIENCE status: null
10-18 09:43:38.050 1914-3643/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 2421:com.google.android.partnersetup/u0a11 for broadcast com.google.android.partnersetup/.RlzPingBroadcastReceiver
10-18 09:43:38.117 12147-12257/? W/Icing: GetUsageReports fallback to slow seek
10-18 09:43:38.120 1914-2954/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 32316:com.android.defcontainer/u0a4 (adj 15): empty #17
10-18 09:43:38.163 1233-2364/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient: Unrecoverable auth exception: Unknown
10-18 09:43:38.163 1233-2364/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
10-18 09:43:38.163 1233-2364/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
10-18 09:43:38.163 1233-2364/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
10-18 09:43:38.163 1233-2364/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at com.google.identitytoolkit.idp.google.GoogleIdpClient$1.call(GoogleIdpClient.java:131)
10-18 09:43:38.163 1233-2364/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at com.google.identitytoolkit.idp.google.GoogleIdpClient$1.call(GoogleIdpClient.java:125)
10-18 09:43:38.163 1233-2364/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at com.google.identitytoolkit.executor.ProgressRequestExecutor$2.doInBackground(ProgressRequestExecutor.java:84)
10-18 09:43:38.163 1233-2364/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at com.google.identitytoolkit.executor.ProgressRequestExecutor$2.doInBackground(ProgressRequestExecutor.java:71)
10-18 09:43:38.163 1233-2364/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
10-18 09:43:38.163 1233-2364/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-18 09:43:38.163 1233-2364/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
10-18 09:43:38.163 1233-2364/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
10-18 09:43:38.163 1233-2364/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
10-18 09:43:38.163 1233-2364/com.application.my_app E/GooglePlusIdpClient:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-18 09:43:38.178 1233-1272/com.application.my_app E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9f355b50
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem, at least partially. The problem was that I had provided the `"package"` name where package name was asked for the keys on Google Developer Console. I should have provided the `"applicationId"` mentioned in my `"build.gradle"`. In my case, both are different. Since in all documentation, it is mentioned to provide package name, I got confused.

After making that change, Google authentication is working. I am looking into Facebook authentication which is still not working.

I have migrated to the latest Gitkit libraries and I found the below functions missing in the new android library :

I am trying to figure out their workarounds :

```
IdToken idToken = client.getSavedIdToken();
Account account = client.getSavedAccount();
```

Below link would explain this part

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Relevant excerpt from the above link

> Therefore, we have decoupled the two usages of package name: The final
>   package that is used in your built .apk's manifest, and is the package
>   your app is known as on your device and in the Google Play store, is
>   the "application id". The package that is used in your source code to
>   refer to your R class, and to resolve any relative activity/service
>   registrations, continues to be called the "package".